# How to create a matrix with multiple variables defining the elements?

Tags: functions, matrix, physics

I am a learner start using Mathematica to study quantum mechanics. In many cases, I am try to construct matrix with functions like this:

For example, let f be a function taking 4 variables x1,x2,x3,x4, where x1 = 0 or 1 or 2 so dest x2, x3, x4.

[ f[0,0,0,0] f[0,0,0,1] f[0,0,0,2] f[0,0,1,0 .....

f[1,0,0,0] f[1,0,0,1] ....
.
.
.
...]

Do any one know how should I use Mathematica functions to generate such a matrix instead of writing them one by one?

Comment: `f @@@ Tuples[{0, 1, 2}, {4}]`

Comment: Use `Table` or `Array`. Those will create 4D-arrays. You can apply `ArrayReshape` afterwards.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started, 1) take the introductory [tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: I'm not sure what "so dest" means in the second paragraph. Perhaps "and so do"?

Answer (score 3):

```
Array[f,{3,3,3,3},{0,0,0,0}]
```

will give you a 4-dimensional matrix.

```
f@@@Tuples[{0,1,2},4]
```

will give you a 1-dimensional list.

In either case, you can reshape as needed.